# Navigation.Removepage cause issue - Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which have page navigation as follows.

Page 1---> Page 2 ---> Page 3 --->Page 4--->Page 5 ---> Rg.plugin.Popup(Page 5)

I have a button at The popup page.What I am trying to do is navigate to Page 2 after the button click in popup(Page 5). I am using Navigation.RemovePage method.This work perfect on android. But in ios it will navigate to page 2 , but I can see the pages remove animations ie; it will slide one by one. I just want to directly navigate to page 2 in ios. How to solve this issue?

What I Have done.

```
   private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
        }

        await PopupNavigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this
Navigation.RemovePage (Navigation.NavigationStack [Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 3]); 
this.Navigation.PopAsync (); // This PopAsync will now go to Page2 if none of them are modals

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last page at the end, not at the start.

Comment: Ok..Let me check

Comment: Hi Ivan thanks for the answer, When I tried your code, I am getting this exception

Comment: Foundation.MonoTouchException: 'Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: CALayerInvalidGeometry Reason: CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; 0 nan]
Native stack trace:

Comment: What will be the reason?

Comment: @Anand The logic I have said should be correct - first remove all other pages and then the last page. It could be that the code is not right, I’ll remove it. I don’t have the time to provide you with the code level support, unfortunately.